# Python stringing functions together and understanding if a functions is the last

Tags: python, class

I created a class called `select` that has a function `s` which executes selection on the data that I initialize the select with.

For example:

```
select(data).s('color=red').s('tast=sweet')
```

This works perfectly fine.

I would like to know at the time the `s` function is executed if it's the last in the line or not. How would I do that?

To clarify:

`select(data).s('color=red').s('tast=sweet')`

`s('color=red')` is NOT the last because it's followed by `.s('tast=sweet')`, while `.s('tast=sweet')` IS the last, because it's not followed by anything.

Comment: You should provide a more concrete example. Declaration of `select` and the function `s`. The example should be re-producible by us. I don't quite understand what you're looking for from your description.

Comment: There isn't, really. If you look at other uses of fluent interfaces (e.g. Java, where it's a common pattern) there's usually an *"OK I'm done"* method.

Comment: you knows each way works and just want a best practice, (or a better solution if there is one). this kind of question is too open to stackoverflow and you can ask in https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Can you clarify why are you trying to achieve this? it can help people focus their explanations

Answer (score 0):

Something in like this may work for you:

```
class Select:
    def __init__(self, query=None):
        self._query = query or {}

    def s(self, **kwargs):
        return Select({**self._query, **kwargs})

    def exec(self):
        print(', '.join('{}={}'.format(k, v) for k, v in self._query.items()))
```

This results in:

```
In [1]: select = Select()

In [2]: select.s(color='red').s(taste='sweet').exec()
color=red, taste=sweet
```

**EDIT:**

A little more elegant:

```
class Select:
    def __init__(self, query=None):
        self._query = query or {}

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        return self._arg_to_query(item)

    def s(self, **kwargs):
        return Select({**self._query, **kwargs})

    def exec(self):
        print(', '.join('{}={}'.format(k, v) for k, v in self._query.items()))

    def _arg_to_query(self, arg):
        def to_query(query):
            return Select({**self._query, arg: query})
        return to_query
```

This results in:

```
In [3]: sel = Select()

In [4]: sel.color('red').taste('sweet').exec()
color=red, taste=sweet
```

or combined:

```
In [5]: sel.color('red').taste('sweet').s(texture='smooth').exec()
color=red, taste=sweet, texture=smooth
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! Appreciate it very much!  So, is there any way to 'know' that in sel.color('red').taste('sweet').exec() 'color' is not the last item, while in sel.color('red').exec() it is the last item

Comment: in python 3.6+ the dictionary is ordered (Guaranteed ordered in 3.7), otherwise you can change the implementation to use a list of tuples `[('color', 'red'), ('taste', 'sweet')]` or an `OrderedDict` from the `collections` module, in any case the sequence is ordered by invocation

Comment: so `self._query[-1]` will give you the las invoked key or tuple depending on what you decided

Comment: right, but you only know the last item if it's already executed. So, while it's at color=red, it doesnt know that taste=sweet is yet to come

Comment: that's the way it works, there no possible way of knowing if theres an upcoming query from within the class itself, but on the other hand remember that its just a class so you don't have to execute it immediately, you can do `prepared_query = sel.color('red').taste('sweet')` and then inspect the instance query before executing it